# Package showkeys, switch off/on key display

Tags: luatex, showkeys

Is there a trick (I have seen no option for that) to switch on/off the printing of the keys?
Switch off would be enough. Because at the end of my draft document I have toc's that help me in my work, and there the keys are more an obstacle then a help.

**EDIT.** Example added:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showkeys} 
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}\label{ch:first}
\section{Introduction}
First page
\section{Conclusion}\label{sec:aaa}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{sec of \nameref{ch:first}}

abc\label{abc}
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{}
xyz\label{xyz}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

> In the table of contents there should be no reference from showkeys

Comment: As usual, add a compilable code example please, something we can work with.

Comment: `showkeys` tries hard not to interfere with the pagination, but it's not guaranteed that line and page breaks will be as good as they could. The simplest way to turn off `showkeys` is to comment out the line `\usepackage{showkeys}`.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you can redefine the printing command. This will affect \label. `\ref` (and `\nameref}`) uses another command and there seem not to be an official interface. But redefining an internal command seems to work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ch1}\label{ch:first}
\section{Introduction}
First page
\section{Conclusion}\label{sec:aaa}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{sec of \nameref{ch:first}}

abc\label{abc}
\ref{xyz} \nameref{ch:first}

\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{}
\makeatletter
\def\SK@@ref#1>#2\SK@{}
\makeatletter

xyz\label{xyz} 
\ref{xyz} \nameref{ch:first}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow a documented feature

Comment: In a normal case it works, but in case of a table of contents/list, where the label have been defined earlier, it doesn't. I guess that the generation of the extra output is stopped, but not the printing of labels.

Comment: You didn't provide any code so it wasn't possible to test your setup.

Comment: It was not a criticism, just an info for people looking for solutions. I've edited the question adding an example of the problem described.

Comment: I added an edit for \ref and \nameref.